# Router Issue: Multiple wi-fi connections crashes the router

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking, crash

Occasionally my Linksys router will drop all Wi-Fi connections if there are multiple wi-fi connections on the router.  Sometimes the whole router will even crash when there are multiple wi-fi connections going to the same router.

For example, if i have my laptop using the wi-fi connection from my router, and my friend starts up his laptop to connect to the router via wi-fi, both our wi-fi connections will drop, and occasionally the whole router crashes.

I was wondering if this is a known issue and/or if there are any router settings I should take a look at.  I had originally thought i just had a bad router, but after talking to one of my friends, he is having the same issue.

I can provide specific router info if need be (I am away from Home and do not have the the info right now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for newer firmware on Linksys website and see if it holds anything newer. This is your best guess from giving us 0 information about your Linksys model.

Comment: Updating the firmware fixed the issue.